# Java: How to read content from redirected URLs?

Tags: java

I use the following Java code in a Bean to read a URL's content:

```
String url;
String inputLine;
StringBuilder srcCode=new StringBuilder();

public void setUrl (String value) {
    url = value; 
}

private void scanWebPage() throws IOException {
    try {
         URL dest = new URL(url);
         URLConnection yc =  dest.openConnection();
         yc.setUseCaches(false);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
                        InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            srcCode = srcCode.append (inputLine);
         in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
         srcCode.append("File Not Found") ;
    }
}
```

The code works fine for most URL's, but does not work for redirected URLs. How can I update the above code to read content from redirected URLs? For redirected URLs, I get `"File Not Found"`.

Comment: `java.net.URL` should follow redirects by default (unless you've previously called `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false)`), so you should just see the content of the final target URL.  Assuming of course that the redirect doesn't itself go to a 404 page...

Comment: URL connection will not follow redirects if the protocol changes (i.e, from HTTP to HTTPS). Is this your scenario? Also, are you not allowed to use [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 4):

Give the following a go:

```
    HttpURLConnection yc =  (HttpURLConnection) dest.openConnection();
    yc.setInstanceFollowRedirects( true );
```

In context to your code above:

```
   `String url = "http://java.sun.com";
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder srcCode=new StringBuilder();



    URL dest = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection yc =  (HttpURLConnection) dest.openConnection();
    yc.setInstanceFollowRedirects( true );
    yc.setUseCaches(false);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        srcCode = srcCode.append (inputLine);
    }

    in.close();`
```

Modified further to help you diagnose what is going on. This code turns off auto redirection and then manually follows the Location headers printing out as it goes along.

```
@Test
public void f() throws IOException {
    String url = "http://java.sun.com";


    fetchURL(url);
}


private HttpURLConnection fetchURL( String url ) throws IOException {
    URL dest = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection yc =  (HttpURLConnection) dest.openConnection();
    yc.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    yc.setUseCaches(false);

    System.out.println( "url = " + url );

    int responseCode = yc.getResponseCode();
    if ( responseCode >= 300 && responseCode < 400 ) { // brute force check, far too wide
        return fetchURL( yc.getHeaderField( "Location") );
    }

    System.out.println( "yc.getResponseCode() = " + yc.getResponseCode() );

    return yc;
}
```

Comment: Chris - Thanks, but this did not work. The redirected urls are like "mini urls" which get changed to a true url when entered in the web browser, but through java code, they do not change and are termed as invalid urls.

Comment: What is the URL that you are going to? I tested the code above and found that it follows the redirect for the url above. In your case is your URL redirecting to a different protocol? If so then that is probably your problem as HttpURLConnection will not follow those. If that is the case then I would personally use a library such as the one included in Play2, or Apache HttpCommons. Alternatively you can always set auto follow to false and then read out the Location header yourself and then fetch that URL explicitly yourself.

Answer (score 0):

its not the debuggin of your prog , but you can consider this one

```
public class GetURLData
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String url = "the url you want the response from";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
            try 
            {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                char[] buf = new char[8000];
                int l = 0;
                    while (l >= 0) 
                    {
                        builder.append(buf, 0, l);
                        l = in.read(buf);
                    }
                System.out.println(builder.toString);
            } catch (Exception e) 
        {
                System.out.println("Exception is :"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```